# Can glew conflict with glew in other libraries on Linux?

Tags: linux, opengl, glew, one-definition-rule

I have a dynamic library that has`glew.c` in the build and builds using `GLEW_STATIC`.  If another library is linked into the same application and also includes GLEW in some way, is there a possibility that this could causes problems on Linux due to the one definition rule?

Answer (score 1):

It will be fine as long as you do not export any of the symbols. All GLEW symbols should have the “hidden” attribute. You can do this by setting the default visibility to “hidden” using `-fvisibilty=hidden` at compile time. You can use `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` to explicitly export the symbols you want to export.

Honestly, I cannot reconcile this behavior with the ODR. I would cautiously say that the ODR does not account for symbol visibility.